How to implement left-to-right or right-to-left swipe in Flet Python?
I was Working Students Attendance system in Flet,
It very basic,
the list shows sort by name,
if we want mark, just swipe L-R,
If mistakenly swiped, then long press open student details page then remove
its my sample code
row = ft.Container(
                    content=ft.Row([
                        in_time_text,
                        ft.Text("     "),
                        ft.Text(
                            disabled=False, size=responsive_values["font_size"] - 1, expand=True,
                            italic=bool(record.get('current_date')),
                            spans=[
                                ft.TextSpan(
                                    f"{record.get('name', 'N/A')}",
                                    ft.TextStyle(decoration=None),
                                ),
                            ]),
                        ft.Icon(
                            name=ft.icons.PEOPLE_ALT if record.get('current_date') else ft.icons.PEOPLE_ALT_OUTLINED,
                            size=20,
                            color=ft.colors.GREY if record.get('current_date') else ft.colors.BLUE,
                        )
                    ], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN),
                    bgcolor=ft.colors.GREY_100 if record.get('current_date') else ft.colors.WHITE,
                    padding=ft.padding.symmetric(vertical=2, horizontal=10),
                    margin=ft.margin.symmetric(vertical=0),
                    width=responsive_values["container_width"] - 20,
                    height=40,
                    # on_click=on_click_data if not record.get('current_date') else None,
                    on_click=on_long_press_data,
                    on_long_press=on_long_press_data,
                    data=record,
                )

use the same code when will swipe L-R,
def on_long_press_data(e):
                    new_content = create_participant_details_page(
                        page=page,
                        record=e.control.data,  # Assuming the record is stored in the control's data attribute
                        responsive_values=responsive_values,
                        current_user_email=current_user_email
                    )
                    page.controls.clear()
                    page.controls.extend(new_content)
                    page.update()

i was written, long_press, i want swipe options,
i want like when we try WhatsApp / Contacts app
